# Zepto.js Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'swipe'

Tags: javascript, swipe, zepto

I made a custom build of zepto .js that includes the touch module. When I inspect my zepto.js file I find this at the end

```
,a(window).on("scroll",l)}),["swipe","swipeLeft","swipeRight","swipeUp","swipeDown","doubleTap","tap","singleTap","longTap"].forEach(function(b){a.fn[b]=function(a){return this.on(b,a)}})}(Zepto)
```

This makes me believe that the swipe is loaded in the js file.

At the bottom of my html I have this:

```
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/zepto.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(".row.main").swipe(function(){
    window.location.href = "editorial.html";
  })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't understand why I get the `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'swipe'` error.

can someone help me out?